# Intellij error - test framework quit unexpectedly intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

I have been trying to run junit test but facing this issue constantly. I tried to look for answers on the internet but nothing helped.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qltNy.png)

[image]

Comment: This looks like some uncommon system behaviour.. restart your IntelliJ and pay attention that `com.MyTest.TestClass` is not a valid path to class.

Comment: I restarted it and mvn clean as well but didn't work. The class name is dummy one.

Comment: Can you share a bit more information of what you're exactly doing? and what's the full log? you seem to be using Azul's Zulu JDK. Why?

Comment: I have been trying to run junit test from intellij and this message I get. Yes, I am using zulu open jdk 8.

Answer (score 7):

If there is an error e.g.

> "*`CommandLineWrapper` is ill-suited for launching apps on Java 9+...*"

Then, try the following workaround in IntelliJ IDEA:

Run -> Edit configurations -> select the failed running config -> Shorten command line: @argfile (Java 9+) -> OK

Answer (score 4):

For IntelliJ 2019 and above go to :
`Settings-> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Running Tests` and
Uncheck `argLine`

Comment: doesn't help and you didn't even explain what it does

Comment: I was having the same issue but with message: "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found". This fixed it, thanks. 
If you will, what is exactly happening when the argLine is checked? Why do we need to uncheck it now?

Answer (score 1):

I had previously installed zulu and Oracle Java and then switched between the two quite a bit.
I ended up having many JDKs

Here's what helped me.

In intelliJ, go to Run, the Edit Configurations.
In the Run/Debug Configurations window, under Build and run section, select 'Java Bundled'.

To make sure this applies for all tests, click on the edit template icon (the spanner), select JUnit and then in the Build and run section select 'java Bundled'

Make sure all the configurations under JUnit has 'java Bundled' as well

Click Apply and Ok. Try to run the tests now and it should probably work.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but it has been resolved by updating the Intellij latest version 2020.3. Now i am able to run the test without any error. Please check below link for latest Intellij versions
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I had some incompatible/old dependencies in my SBT project.

I updated the versions of every 3rd party in the SBT config and running ZIO tests in IntelliJ started working.

Answer (score 0):

For me also, the problem was that I made a change in the dependecies and the dependecy updated was incompatible in the SBT project.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31206104)

Answer (score 0):

JUnit 5 and/or Intellij needs an extra dependency to be able to run tests:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because two tests had the same name and namespace.

What actually happened: deleting a folder to which a class was pointing, convinced(?) PHPStorm to create a copy of the folder of the class.